# Is possible to make a non-idempotent function idempotent and resist to failures at the same time?

Tags: distributed, formal-methods

I try to design an idempotent function that would resist to failures in a concurrent system while making use of a non-idempotent one.

I've been able to get something working with a

```
if lockAcquired 
    then : execute the non-idempotent function 
           write result
    else : wait until result available
           read result
return result
```

But it assumes that the "writing" thread doesn't fail between acquiring the lock and writing the result.

Are there some known algorithm out there that solve this problem ? (I guess it would be a totally different approach)

In order to reason about the problem, an example of non-idempotent function would be "sending an email".